# How can I get a HOC to expose defaultProps of WrappedComponent to parent?

Tags: reactjs, higher-order-components

I have a React parent, which works with the children props. Right now, it only sees the inline props of the Component and not the defaultProps. I augmented the parent to read children element defaultProps also.

Rendering will look something like this:

```
<Parent>
  <HOC>
    <Child_Element_With_Default_Props />
  </HOC>
</Parent>
```

The problem is the children element has a HOC around it, which hides the defaultProps.

Is there a way for the Parent to get access to the defaultProps of Child?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you should be able to add defaultProps to a component that HOC returns:

```
const hoc = (Wrapped) => {
   const newComp = () => <Wrapped />
   newComp.defaultProps = Wrapped.defaultProps;
   return newComp;
}
```

(haven't tested this code, but should work)